# How do we map variables to objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I've been writing code like this

var image

then in method:

image = Resources.Load("image", typeof(Material)) as Material

but I see some tutorials just define the instance variables, and I see no code that maps the object from my project to that variable.  I'm guessing this is done in the IDE and its some basic thing that I didn't read about while learning unity.

Can someone point me to the instructions for this, or what its called for me to go research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be referring to setting properties in the inspector.  Unity's inspector allows you to modify many different types of values, ranging from the simple integer and boolean values to allowing you to drag and drop prefabs and other GameObjects.  There is a fairly comprehensive tutorial [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingValueProperties.html), detailing the different types of variables that can be set in the inspector.

Comment: I see the issue.  I should choose the script, then go to the inspector.  At the top I see my exposed variable.